# Converting C# Razor Syntax to VB.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

Can someone please help me converting the following razor syntax to it's equivalent vb.net razor syntax?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
  .Name("menu") //The name of the menu is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
  .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
  {
      mappings.For<category>(binding => binding //define first level of menu
          .ItemDataBound((item, category) => //define mapping between menu item properties and the model properties
              {
              item.Text = category.CategoryName;
              })
          .Children(category => category.Products)); //define which property of the model contains the children
      mappings.For<product>(binding => binding
          .ItemDataBound((item, product) =>
          {
              item.Text = product.ProductName;
          }));
})
```

)
--UPDATE

I have manage to convert the above code in sections but now getting the following error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

      Compiler Error Message: BC30561: 'Html' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.Mvc, Kendo.Mvc.UI'.

Source Error:


Line 2:  @ModelType IEnumerable(Of MenuCategory)
Line 3:  
Line 4:  @(Html.Kendo().Menu() _
Line 5:              .Name("TestMenu") _
Line 6:              .BindTo(Model, Sub(mappings)

  Source File: C:\Documents and Settings\vivekba\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test\test\Views\Home\TestMenu.vbhtml    Line: 4
```

---

my converted view looks like this

```
 @Imports test.Models
  @ModelType IEnumerable(Of TestMenuCategory)

  @(Html.Kendo().Menu() _
        .Name("TestMenu") _
        .BindTo(Model,
                Sub(mappings)
                        mappings.For(Of TestMenuCategory)(
                            Sub(x)
                                    x.ItemDataBound(
                                        Sub(item, menu)
                                                item.Text = menu.Name
                                        End Sub) _
                                                .Children(
                                                    Function(menu)
                                                            Return menu.SubItem
                                                    End Function)



                                    mappings.For(Of TestMenuItem)(Sub(bindings)
                                                                            bindings.ItemDataBound(Sub(testItem, menuItem)
                                                                                                         testItem.Text = "test"
                                                                                                 End Sub)
                                                                  End Sub)



                            End Sub)
                End Sub)
        )
```

Comment: or guide me in the right direction on how can i convert it?

Comment: The syntax relies om a @{do domething} block. You can access VB objects. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: i know that. i have tried rewriting this in vb.net but get stuck at ItemDataBound(item, category) on how can i rewrite this? Visual Studio isn't offering any intellisense help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix if anyone looking for.

```
@Imports test.Models
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of TestMenuCategory)

  @(Html.Kendo().Menu() _
    .Name("TestMenu") _
    .BindTo(Model,
            Sub(mappings)
                    mappings.For(Of TestMenuCategory)(
                        Sub(x)
                                x.ItemDataBound(
                                    Sub(item, menu)
                                            item.Text = menu.Name
                                    End Sub) _
                                            .Children(
                                                Function(menu)
                                                        Return menu.SubItem
                                                End Function)



                                mappings.For(Of TestMenuItem)(Sub(bindings)
                                                                        bindings.ItemDataBound(Sub(testItem, menuItem)
                                                                                                     testItem.Text = menuItem.name
                                                                                             End Sub)
                                                              End Sub)



                        End Sub)
            End Sub)
    )
```